# C++ std::stack empties after each iteration of while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, stack

I'm trying to write a function used to parse XML tags for XML like this:

```xml
<Employee>
    <salary>40000</salary> <name>John Doe</name> <id>1234</id>
    <address>2230 W. Treeline Dr.</address>
    <city>Tucson</city>
    <state>Arizona</state>
    <country>USA</country>
    <phone>520-742-2448</phone>
</Employee> <Employee>
    <salary>60000</salary> <name>Jane Doe</name> <id>4321</id> </Employee>
<Employee>
    <salary>140000</salary>
    <state>Michigan</state>
    <name>Jack Dough</name>
    <id>12345</id>
    <city>Dearborn</city>
    <country>USA</country>
    <phone>303-427-0153</phone>
    <address>24437 Princeton</address>
</Employee>
```

I'm using an `std::stack` to keep track of the tags. When an opening tag (e.g. `<Employee>`) is encountered, a string representation of the tag name (`Employee`) is pushed onto the stack, and, assuming the XML is written correctly, encountering the matching closing tag (e.g. `</Employee>`) causes the tag name to be popped off of the stack. However, I have run into an issue where a string is pushed onto the stack so the stack has a size of 1. When the body of the while loop is reached and the body is executed a second time, the stack is emptied. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Why does my stack "reset" every time the `while` loop reiterates?

```cpp
static void fromXML(std::istream& in_stream) {
    std::stack<std::string> tags;
    std::string temp;
    std::string tagName;
    std::getline(in_stream, temp);
    std::istringstream ss(temp);

    bool building_employee = true;
    int _id;
    std::string _name;
    std::string _address = "";
    std::string _city = "";
    std::string _state = "";
    std::string _country = "";
    std::string _phone = "";
    double _salary = 0.0;        

    while(building_employee && std::getline(ss, temp, '<')) {
        std::cout << "Size: " << tags.size() << std::endl; // Prints "0"


        std::getline(ss, tagName, '>');
        ss.ignore(256, '<');

        if (tagName == "") { }
        else if ( !tags.empty() && tagName == "/" + tags.top() ) {
            std::cout << "Popping " << tags.top() << std::endl;
            tags.pop();
        }
        else if ((tags.empty() && tagName == "Employee") || (!tags.empty() && tagName != "Employee")) {
            std::cout << "Pushing " << tagName << std::endl;
            tags.push(tagName);                
        }
        else {                 
            std::cerr << "Problem with XML." << std::endl;
        }

        if (tagName == "/Employee") { building_employee = false; }
        else if (tagName == "id") { _id = std::stoi(temp); }
        else if (tagName == "name") { _name = temp; }


        if (!building_employee) { std::cout << "Employee end." << std::endl; }
        if(in_stream.eof()) {
            std::cout << "Error: End of file reached without closing <" << temp << ">" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Size: " << tags.size() << std::endl; // Prints "1" after pushing one string onto the stack
    }
    if (temp == "/Employee") { std::cout << "Employee object succesfully created" << std::endl; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: *When the body of the while loop is reached and the body is executed a second time, the stack is emptied.* -- How do you know all of this when you haven't indicated you debugged your program?  If you claim you debugged your program, then when you single-stepped through the while loop, what line of code "empties the stack"?

Answer (score 1):

Let me be polite for other and do [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve") for them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <stack>

static void fromXML(std::istream& in_stream) {
    std::stack<std::string> tags;
    std::string temp;
    std::string tagName;
    std::getline(in_stream, temp);
    std::istringstream ss(temp);

    bool building_employee = true;
    int _id;
    std::string _name;
    std::string _address = "";
    std::string _city = "";
    std::string _state = "";
    std::string _country = "";
    std::string _phone = "";
    double _salary = 0.0;        

    while(building_employee && std::getline(ss, temp, '<')) {
        std::cout << "Size 1: " << tags.size() << std::endl; // Prints "0"


        std::getline(ss, tagName, '>');
        ss.ignore(256, '<');

        if (tagName == "") { }
        else if ( !tags.empty() && tagName == "/" + tags.top() ) {
            std::cout << "Popping " << tags.top() << std::endl;
            tags.pop();
        }
        else if ((tags.empty() && tagName == "Employee") || (!tags.empty() && tagName != "Employee")) {
            std::cout << "Pushing " << tagName << std::endl;
            tags.push(tagName);                
        }
        else {                 
            std::cerr << "Problem with XML." << std::endl;
        }

        if (tagName == "/Employee") { building_employee = false; }
        else if (tagName == "id") { _id = std::stoi(temp); }
        else if (tagName == "name") { _name = temp; }


        if (!building_employee) { std::cout << "Employee end." << std::endl; }
        if(in_stream.eof()) {
            std::cout << "Error: End of file reached without closing <" << temp << ">" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Size 2: " << tags.size() << std::endl; // Prints "1" after pushing one string onto the stack
    }
    if (temp == "/Employee") { std::cout << "Employee object succesfully created" << std::endl; }
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input(
        "<Employee>\n"
        "    <salary>40000</salary> <name>John Doe</name><id>1234</id>\n"
        "    <address>2230 W. Treeline Dr.</address>\n"
        "    <city>Tucson</city>\n"
        "    <state>Arizona</state>\n"
        "    <country>USA</country>\n"
        "    <phone>520-742-2448</phone>\n"
        "</Employee> <Employee>\n"
        "    <salary>60000</salary> <name>Jane Doe</name> <id>4321</id> </Employee>\n"
        "<Employee>\n"
        "    <salary>140000</salary>\n"
        "    <state>Michigan</state>\n"
        "    <name>Jack Dough</name>\n"
        "    <id>12345</id\n"
        "    <city>Dearborn</city>\n"
        "    <country>USA</country>\n"
        "    <phone>303-427-0153</phone>\n"
        "    <address>24437 Princeton</address>\n"
        "</Employee>)\n");
    fromXML(input);
}
```

> Why does my stack "reset" every time the while loop reiterates?

The stack does not reset, the loop does not iterate. Follow @JiveDadson advice and use a debugger.

The key of the issue consists of two lines

```
std::getline(in_stream, temp);
std::istringstream ss(temp);
```

You read one line there and your loop operates on this line only. Since it is the only line, the loop's body is executed once only. Remove those lines and change all corresponding occurrences of `ss` in the code to `in_stream`.

```
while(building_employee && std::getline(in_stream, temp, '<')) {
    // ...
    std::getline(in_stream, tagName, '>');
    in_stream.ignore(256, '<');
```

Comment: This is no answer. This is a comment :)

Comment: Good effort, but I'm not sure you should get in the habit of providing the MCVE that should be provided by the questioner. A helpful comment to provide a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) insures that the question is useful to other readers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It was a master class :-)

Comment: Also a typo `std::getline(ss, tagName, '>');ss` has a stray `ss` dangling off the end `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thak you. It is because of my mouse wheel, it is pressed very easily and it pastes last selections randomly while scrolling.

Comment: we shouldn't really provide a debugging service here.